# JSON phrase javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
  "status_code":200,
  "result":{
    "leads":[
      {},
      {},
      {}
    ],
    "patients":[
     {},
     {},
     {},
     {}
   ],
    "assessments":[
     {},
     {}
   ],
    "worklogs":[
    ],
    "schedules":[
      {},
      {},
      {}
    ],
    "comments":[],
    "masters":{
      "services":[
        {},
        {}
      ],
      "managers":[
        {},
        {},
        {}
      ]
    },
    "feedbacks":[
    ]
  }
}
```

How to parse above JSON and store a particular array in the JSON angular5 simply return the particular array value
How can I parse the file and extract single values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: What did you tried?